# How to override or modify parent pom repository in child pom?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

How to override or modify parent pom from child pom?

I tried to override using settings.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail, with an example?

Comment: If you have control over the parent pom.xml then go ahead and modify directly. Otherwise you can override the dependency and plugins and basically most part in child pom. Also, look into https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html. Think of overriding a base class.